# pages number compression with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm wondering if there is a way to make the bbx bibliography style automatically convert a pages range (e.g. 167-169) to the compressed form 167-9, so that unchanged digits are not repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
```

see [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), 4.6.4 Miscellaneous Commands